# ¿Cómo se dice "hacer nada" o "no hacer nada"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

¿Como se debe decir "hacer nada" o "no hacer nada"? Yo como nativo, lo he oido siempre como "no hacer nada", solo que me entro la duda si en realidad es correcto.

Comment: En coordinación sería posible *hacer algo o nada*. Pero excepto en este caso, tendría que ser *no hacer nada* o *nada hacer* (pero siendo objeto en vez de sujeto, tendría que ser un contexto enfático o contrastante porque si no, un objeto suegro teóricamente obligaría la coaparición de un pronombre átono que me suena horrible con *nada*)

Comment: un objeto *antepuesto* (no *suegro*)

Comment: Estar de hueva.

Comment: No se dice nada sin contexto.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se dice "no hacer nada". En inglés es "to do nothing". Esto lo explica la RAE donde se indica que en español hay casos donde se usa [la doble negación](http://www.rae.es/consultas/doble-negacion-no-vino-nadie-no-hice-nada-no-tengo-ninguna).

> En español existe un esquema particular de negación, que permite
>   combinar el adverbio no con la presencia de otros elementos que tienen
>   también sentido negativo. Los adverbios nunca, jamás, tampoco, los
>   indefinidos nadie, nada, ninguno, la locución en la/mi/tu/su vida y
>   los grupos que contienen la palabra ni aparecen siempre en oraciones
>   de sentido negativo. Si estos elementos van antepuestos al verbo, este
>   no va acompañado del adverbio de negación no: Nunca voy al teatro; Él
>   tampoco está de acuerdo; Jamás lo haré; Nadie lo sabe; Nada de lo que
>   dice tiene sentido; Ninguno de ellos es actor; En su vida lo
>   conseguirá; Ni su padre lo perdonaría. Pero si van pospuestos al
>   verbo, este debe ir necesariamente precedido del adverbio no: No voy
>   nunca al teatro; Él no está de acuerdo tampoco; No lo haré jamás; No
>   lo sabe nadie; No tiene sentido nada de lo que dice; No es actor
>   ninguno de ellos; No lo conseguirá en su vida; No lo perdonaría ni su
>   padre. La concurrencia de esas dos «negaciones» no anula el sentido
>   negativo del enunciado, sino que lo refuerza.
>
> Fuente: [RAE](http://www.rae.es/consultas/doble-negacion-no-vino-nadie-no-hice-nada-no-tengo-ninguna)

Comment: Alfredo, se te echa de menos. ¿Para cuándo una nueva pregunta o respuesta tuya? Necesitamos a alguien para atender las pregutnas sobre México : )

Comment: No hacer nada can be **doing nothing**, especially as an utterance.